# Best possible way to automate encrypted RDS mysql replication between 2 AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, rds, amazon-rds

I have 2 AWS accounts 1. Production 2. Development. I want to replicate the development RDS encrypted database to production account in a automated way. VPC peering is not allowed between the accounts but I can share the KMS keys between the accounts.

I read few blogs but they are talking about manual process. Any suggestions

Comment: My suggestion: Don't do it. The point of having separate development/production databases is to have **separate** development/production databases. Development is where you're likely to screw things up - you don't want `DELETE * FROM users` replicating across. Instead, look into database **migrations**, done at a code level in your application itself.

Comment: You can try how AWS suggests to [replicate with a database server outside AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html). It's application level so encrypted disk is irrelevant. I also strongly suggest that this is a terrible idea. I think manual via dumps is likely better.

Comment: Use something like [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org) instead so you don't shoot yourself in the foot later